# Authentication on a simple PHP RESTful API service

Tags: php, api, authentication, slim, restful-authentication

I have a developed a very simple PHP API based on the PHP Slim Framework. It does nothing more then doing some SQL queries and returning an JSON object whenever I call it. I am accessing this API on another website through CURL.

My question is: Since the URL of the API is basically public now, what is the best way of securing it? My first thought was HTTP Basic Auth which would be easy and I could pass through the http headers. However I think it's not really safe as long as there is no HTTPS connection (since the website would literally pass username+password over to the API in plain text). Also I would have to store the credentials in PHP code on my website, which I think is not really optimal.

The next solution I've found is token based authentication, which would have the advantage of not having to authorize on each request but might be more tricky to implement. Also I have no experience with that yet whatsoever.

Also I read OAuth/OAuth2 is the way to go.

The thing is: I am planning to use the same API on a mobile application soon.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Most people do use OAuth/OAuth2, but you could always start by writing your own token validation and require the token be sent with the API headers. You could check for its existence and then validate it accordingly. Using token auth is not complicated. Just take some time and sit down with whatever you decide to implement. Code slowly until you wrap your head around it all. If you looking to port to mobile apps, I would definitely recommend using a token authentication.

Comment: Cool thanks. So OAuth = token based correct? I am actually reading a lot of things about it and a lot of people also suggest it. I think I just haven't quite got the mechanism of signing a request (e.g. in the app) and authenticate on the restful api.

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at my exemple of JSON web token authentication with slim3 here https://github.com/letsila/slim3-jwt-auth-example

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) which, even though was designed for SOAP APIs, works quite well with REST APIs as well. It is basically a token-based authentication, with a temporary token and a nonce file on the server side.

You have some libraries that implement this in PHP, if you're looking for examples, for instance a [Symfony2 bundle](https://github.com/escapestudios/EscapeWSSEAuthenticationBundle).

WS-Security is the middle-ground between HTTP Basic Auth - which is insecure without HTTPS - and OAuth - which might be more complicated to implement.

Comment: There is no such thing as WS-Security for REST

Comment: As stated by O'Reilly here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html ; "WSSE is a family of open security specifications for web services, specifically SOAP web services. However, the Username Token algorithm is not SOAP-specific; it can be easily adapted to work within the HTTP authentication framework". It is indeed originally a SOAP Extension, however this doesn't mean it can't be applied to REST web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [slim-jwt](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth) 
,It will provider a full implamtation for jwt ,You can use it as middelware

Comment: The implementation you mention **requires** HTTPS, while the OP specifically said he needs to use this over HTTP.

Comment: You can allow http connection by adding this  
    "secure" => false,
In your middle ware initialization